# iOS does not show/play video in UIWebView iframe

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, video, uiwebview

I use UIWebView with the:

```
var html:String = "<iframe src='http://46.101.234.111/trailers/suicide_squads_1' width='100%' height='200px' scrolling='no' frameborder='no'></iframe>"

cell.trailerView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

but it doesn't show/play the video on start. It just show play icon on white row and when I press on it - nothing happens.

iframe works, I checked it. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Videos on the iPhone will not auto play from websites. Also make sure the video is in a format that can be played on an iPhone.

Comment: I do not need in autoplay and my video format is mp4, so I think that's fine. Look at my question. I put a screenshot, so you can understand what I mean

Comment: mp4 doesn't mean it's in a format that can be played on iOS, I just tried your link in Safari and it doesn't play either but it does in Chrome.

Comment: hmm, strange. It does not play in Safari. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Convert the video file into a quick time video